# How to call one variable in a JavaScript file to another JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

At the moment I have the following lines of code. 
This is the data of coordinates stored in a variable in a JavaScript file called RealMapofIreland.js

```
var Real = [

        [53.286, -5.796], [53.140, -5.778], [52.525, -5.745], [52.152, -6.108], [51.756, -6.459], [51.481, -6.833], [50.987, -7.481], [50.812, -8.470],
        [50.361, -8.668], [50.097, -9.151], [50.217, -9.536], [48.373, -11.469], [48.10009, -11.85785], [49.1027, -13.27869], [49.38237, -14.06971],
        [51.50874, -16.36208], [51.86292, -15.74684], [52.1874, -15.74684], [52.42922, -18.5154], [55.02802, -19.26247], [55.14121, -21.12293],
        [55.5535, -21.59157], [56.897, -20.77103], [56.70451, -18.86696], [56.60789, -18.92206], [56.48676, -17.81227], [56.4382, -17.79416],
        [56.40782, -16.71381], [56.38198, -16.71111], [56.33481, -15.87885], [56.27996, -15.87705], [56.23114, -14.87909], [56.18225, -14.87729],
        [56.18225, -14.16318], [56.15167, -14.07529], [56.12412, -13.70725], [56.10575, -13.70315], [56.08277, -13.19273], [56.05517, -13.20921],
        [55.628, -7.42491], [55.6311, -7.28484], [55.61559, -7.26836], [55.62334, -7.13927], [55.61249, -7.13193], [55.61249, -6.92319],
        [55.33539, -6.77123]

];
```

In another Javascript file called LeafletMap.js, I try to call the variable 'Real' from the RealMapofIreland.js

```
var polyline = L.polyline(
                  Real,
                  { color: 'red', weight: 2 }
               ).addTo(map);
```

Then in the main page I call both JavaScript files:

```
<script  src="js/RealMapofIreland.js"></script>
<script src="js/LeafletMap.js"></script>
```

This does not work. I assumed when both where called in the main page the `Real` in `RealMapodIreland.js` would be passed the `Real` variable data to polyline function in `LeafletMap.js`.

Do I have to call one JavaScript file in another JavaScript file or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Is `Real` in the global scope or is it enclosed within a function?

Comment: Real is a global scope. There is no other code in the RealMapofIreland.js file expect for the Real variable

Comment: are you using `'use strict';`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your description this should work.

Please check the RealMapofIreland.js is loaded before the L.ployline function is called. To check the Real variable is loaded, add the following line before L.ployline:

```
console.log(Real);
```

Then open the developer tool of browser and reload the page, you should observe the Real value is logged. Anything warning like undefined variable should be paid attention to.

If so but that doesn't work either, change the RealMapofIreland.js as following:

```
window.Real = [ ..... ];
```

And L.ployline function like:

```
var polyline = L.polyline(
                  window.Real,
                  { color: 'red', weight: 2 }
               ).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I try to run it as you suggest in the developer tool a warning appear say: Uncaught Reference error:Real is not defined.

Comment: So the RealMapodIreland.js is not loaded completely while the L.polyline is running. Try to Use jQuery's $.getScript to call L.polyline on RealMapodIreland.js loaded.

Comment: 1. Remove `<script  src="js/RealMapofIreland.js"></script>` from your HTML code
2. Use `$.getScript('js/RealMapofIreland.js', function() { L.polyline(Real, {color:'red', weight:2}).addTo(map); });`

Comment: I have found the problem , when naming my javascript file i had left a space in it and when i called it I left no space. it was  <script src="js/RealMapof20Ireland.js"></script> but i mistakenly left a space so it should have been <script src="js/RealMapof%20Ireland.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Define your variable without var. If you define it with var it becomes private to that file and is not global.

```
Real = [

        [53.286, -5.796], [53.140, -5.778], [52.525, -5.745], [52.152, -6.108], [51.756, -6.459], [51.481, -6.833], [50.987, -7.481], [50.812, -8.470],
        [50.361, -8.668], [50.097, -9.151], [50.217, -9.536], [48.373, -11.469], [48.10009, -11.85785], [49.1027, -13.27869], [49.38237, -14.06971],
        [51.50874, -16.36208], [51.86292, -15.74684], [52.1874, -15.74684], [52.42922, -18.5154], [55.02802, -19.26247], [55.14121, -21.12293],
        [55.5535, -21.59157], [56.897, -20.77103], [56.70451, -18.86696], [56.60789, -18.92206], [56.48676, -17.81227], [56.4382, -17.79416],
        [56.40782, -16.71381], [56.38198, -16.71111], [56.33481, -15.87885], [56.27996, -15.87705], [56.23114, -14.87909], [56.18225, -14.87729],
        [56.18225, -14.16318], [56.15167, -14.07529], [56.12412, -13.70725], [56.10575, -13.70315], [56.08277, -13.19273], [56.05517, -13.20921],
        [55.628, -7.42491], [55.6311, -7.28484], [55.61559, -7.26836], [55.62334, -7.13927], [55.61249, -7.13193], [55.61249, -6.92319],
        [55.33539, -6.77123]

];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, to make sure that the files are loaded in the correct order use the "defer" attribute.
   `<script defer src="js/RealMapofIreland.js"></script>
   <script defer src="js/LeafletMap.js"></script>`
2. Try to create window properties data for each of the included files.

   ```
   window.RealMap = {};window.RealMap.Real = [   
               [53.286, -5.796], [53.140, -5.778], [52.525, -5.745], [52.152, -6.108], [51.756, -6.459], [51.481, -6.833], [50.987, -7.481], [50.812, -8.470],
               [50.361, -8.668], [50.097, -9.151], [50.217, -9.536], [48.373, -11.469], [48.10009, -11.85785], [49.1027, -13.27869], [49.38237, -14.06971],
               [51.50874, -16.36208], [51.86292, -15.74684], [52.1874, -15.74684], [52.42922, -18.5154], [55.02802, -19.26247], [55.14121, -21.12293],
               [55.5535, -21.59157], [56.897, -20.77103], [56.70451, -18.86696], [56.60789, -18.92206], [56.48676, -17.81227], [56.4382, -17.79416],
               [56.40782, -16.71381], [56.38198, -16.71111], [56.33481, -15.87885], [56.27996, -15.87705], [56.23114, -14.87909], [56.18225, -14.87729],
               [56.18225, -14.16318], [56.15167, -14.07529], [56.12412, -13.70725], [56.10575, -13.70315], [56.08277, -13.19273], [56.05517, -13.20921],
               [55.628, -7.42491], [55.6311, -7.28484], [55.61559, -7.26836], [55.62334, -7.13927], [55.61249, -7.13193], [55.61249, -6.92319],
               [55.33539, -6.77123]
   ];
   ```

In 'LeafletMap.js'

```
var polyline = L.polyline(
                  window.RealMap.Real,
                  { color: 'red', weight: 2 }
               ).addTo(map);
```